# Return the largest key of two dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

Assume we have two dictionary:

```
a = {0:0, 1:1, 2:2, 3:3, 4:4, 5:5, 6:6, 7:7}
b = {0:0, 1:7, 2:6, 3:5, 4:4, 5:3, 6:2, 7:1}
```

since the keys that have matches key & value pair at `0` and `4` position in dictionary like  *a[0] == b[0] and a[4] == b[4]* but I want to return only key `4` because its higher.

Comment: Key 4 in `a` is the same as key 4 in `b`? Please clarify your question, thanks :)

Comment: the largest key of dictionary a & b is 7 . please clear the objective of the question

Comment: yes, key `4` in `a` is same with key `4` in `b`. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, do you want a new merged dictionary with the largest values? Or just a single key?

Comment: `a[0] == b[0]` and `a[4] == b[4]` is match by key and value, but I only want to return the key[4] because its higher

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In python3:

```
max([k1 for (k1, v1), (k2, v2) in zip(a.items(), b.items()) if v1 == v2])
```

Comment: I don't think you can guarantee that both `items()` methods will return the keys in the same order, even if this works in some implementations. Try to apply this if you remove the `3:5` part from the second dict for example and you will get wrong results.

Comment: Probably I could agree but it is not a problem if you have the dictionaries the user suggested. He doesn't provide more information, so no need for a more general solution.

Comment: Note also that it returns an error if there is no common key/value pairs between the two dictionaries.

Comment: Yes... the same with all the rest of the solutions

Comment: @spadarian  Except mine I have just posted : it deals with this case with no error.

Comment: Spadarian despite workin in CPython I do *not* think that there is nothing that ensures that even having the same keys the dict view provided by `items()` will have the same order in both cases.

Answer (score 3):

In python 3:

```
a = {0:0, 1:1, 2:2, 3:3, 4:4, 5:5, 6:6, 7:7}
b = {0:0, 1:7, 2:6, 3:5, 4:4, 5:3, 6:2, 7:1}

max(k for k in a.keys() if k in b and a[k] == b[k])
```

Take into account that a `ValueError` will be raised if there is no common pair of keys and values in the 2 dicts. Use a `try: ... except ValueError: ...` statemente to handle this apropriately.

Lets break it into part to understand it more precisely:

```
[k for k in a.keys()]
```

[List-comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) that will iterate over all the keys in the first `dict` (`a`). Now we want to filter it:

```
[k for k in a.keys() if k in b]
```

This first filtering step ensures that the key is also in the second `dict` (`b`).

```
[k for k in a.keys() if k in b and a[k] == b[k]]
```

And this second step ensures that the values of both dicts are the same for this key. So by now we have a list with all the keys that have the same value in both `dict`s.

```
max([k for k in a.keys() if k in b and a[k] == b[k]])
```

The list-comprehension can be replaced by a generator as we do not need the `list` itself for anything, so the square brackets can be removed.

```
max(k for k in a.keys() if k in b and a[k] == b[k])
```

Compute the maximum of the list. This is where the `ValueError`can get raised if the list is empty as `max([])` raises `ValueError`. This would mean that there is no common pair of key-values.

```
try:
    print(max(k for k in a.keys() if k in b and a[k] == b[k]))
except ValueError:
    print("No common pair of key-value.")
```

Comment: Note that it returns an error if there is no common key/value pairs between the two dictionaries.

Comment: @LaurentH. Errors are your friends, handle them to avoid the program crashing but don't try to avoid them. Use a simple `try: ... except ValueError: ...` around this line and you will know when there is no matching keys, and handle that situation properly.

Comment: I fully agree with your solution and explanation, now you have added how you handle the case of "no common pair of key/value". Thanks for this completion.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use set intersection here:

```
a = {0:0, 1:1, 2:2, 3:3, 4:4, 5:5, 6:6, 7:7}
b = {0:0, 1:7, 2:6, 3:5, 4:4, 5:3, 6:2, 7:1}

matches = set(a.items()).intersection(b.items())
# {(0, 0), (4, 4)}

try:
    print(max(matches)[0])
except ValueError:
    print("Cannot get max of empty set")

# 4
```

Comment: Nice use of tuple ordering, I like it

Comment: @Adirio Cheers. i also like your solution, nice and clear :).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you this very basic solution in Python3. Additonnally to the other currently proposed solutions, it does not fail into error if there is no common key/value pairs between the two dictionaries. I also added lots of comments for better understanding and readability:

```
a = {0:0, 1:1, 2:2, 3:3, 4:4, 5:5, 6:6, 7:7}
b = {0:0, 1:7, 2:6, 3:5, 4:4, 5:3, 6:2, 7:1}

# Initialize the result (output)
result = None

# Get the common keys between the 2 dictionaries
commonKeys = [k for k in a.keys() if k in b.keys()]

# Loop on these common keys
for k in commonKeys:
    # Update result:
    # - if the value is identical between the 2 dictionaries
    # - and if current result is lower than this value
    if a[k] == b[k]:
        if ((result == None) or (result < a[k])):
            result = a[k]

# Display result value ("None" if not found)
print(result)
```

Comment: You are considering that printing `None` is a valid error handling mechanic but it may not be for his usecase, we do **not** have enough info about it

Comment: Yes, this is a choice I made. But differently from the other posted solutions ( at the time I am posting this comment, of course), I have shown explicitly how I deal with this case.